Compress PDF without any images or streams
I am looking for a solution to compress PDFs, which which don't contains any images (they will have only text in them).
I am using below code snippet to Compress PDFs but this is for PDFs which contains the Images. but if PDFs don't contains the images then it does not compress it, sometimes it does but to only 100KB to 200KB only.
Code
 (context as AppCompatActivity).lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val reader = PdfReader(inputPath, password.toByteArray())
            //pdfOptimize(reader)
            compressReader(reader)
            saveReader(reader)
            reader.close()

            onPDFCompletion(outputPath)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("PDFCompressionActivityTEST", "execute: ${e.message}")
            onPDFFailed(e.message)
        } catch (e: DocumentException) {
            onPDFFailed(e.message)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            onPDFFailed(e.message)
        }

    }


 @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun compressReader(reader: PdfReader) {
    val n = reader.xrefSize
    var `object`: PdfObject?
    var stream: PRStream
    for (i in 0 until n) {
        `object` = reader.getPdfObject(i)
        if (`object` == null || !`object`.isStream) continue
        stream = `object` as PRStream
        compressStream(stream)
    }
    reader.removeUnusedObjects()
}

 @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun compressStream(stream: PRStream) {
    val pdfSubType = stream[PdfName.SUBTYPE]
    println(stream.type())
    if (pdfSubType != null && pdfSubType.toString() == PdfName.IMAGE.toString()) {
        val image = PdfImageObject(stream)
        val imageBytes = image.imageAsBytes
        val bmp: Bitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size) ?: return
        val width = bmp.width
        val height = bmp.height
        val outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val outCanvas = Canvas(outBitmap)
        outCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0f, 0f, null)
        val imgBytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        outBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, imgBytes)
        stream.clear()
        stream.setData(imgBytes.toByteArray(), false, PRStream.BEST_COMPRESSION)
        stream.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT)
        stream.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE)
        stream.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE)
        stream.put(PdfName.WIDTH, PdfNumber(width))
        stream.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, PdfNumber(height))
        stream.put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, PdfNumber(8))
        stream.put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB)
    }
}


  @Throws(DocumentException::class, IOException::class)
private fun saveReader(reader: PdfReader) {
    val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(outputPath))
    stamper.setFullCompression()
    stamper.close()
}

I saw some apps on Play Store, all are able to compress PDFs (which don't contains the images). But my logic is not able to do it.

It's not like that, What I observed when I am using the above method to compress a pdf which doesn't contain images then it's size is not getting reduced that much compared to any others apps or online tools. That's why I thought there will be any other way to achieve it. @KJ

Quite often in text based PDF's a lot of the size is due to embedded fonts.
Some fonts contain glyphs for many languages and special characters leading to having 3000 plus glyphs adding a couple of hundred Kb to the PDF file.
While your PDF might only use characters from the ASCII range (up to 127 or less)
Thus you could reduce the file size by using a "sparse" set of glyphs (the glyphs of only the characters used in the text).
Note this is less common practise now because some font's Licenses don't allow you to modify the font, but some tools still might do it (ignoring any possible Legal issues)
Also making a "sparse" version of font might make it uneditable without changing the embedded font because it won't have the glyphs for the new characters.
But for font's that you know have a License that allows you to modify the font and you are not worried about edit-ability then you could generate a sparse version.
Sorry no code to do this but a lot of tools that did sparse font's used a Google tool to do this called "sfntly" which does have a java package.

Depends on your definition of Good, a Good PDF writer won't break the Licenses on the font's so is likely to include the whole font and not just for the characters it needs.

It always helps to have a real example of a PDF so let's remove all images from this page and save as PDF. We get before this answer 2 fairly sparse simple pages.

That is about 5 KB pure text, even with padded white space. Within the PDF that is about 4,253 bytes, and we can compress that down to 2.04 KB so that means "Halved" ?

The bigger problem is it is already compressed within the PDF as 2 compressed streams. Page 1 text content is 4584 bytes as compressed
12 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 4584>> stream
xœÍ=]«,7Žïý+êyaÉ–m.................

Page 2 is compressed as
32 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 5101>> stream
xœí\ÛŠ$Ir}Ï¯ˆgÁø˜¹.........

So the two pages of plain text need many more bytes to describe their compressed layout.
The whole file is when decompressed 207 KB (212,132 bytes) and when it is compressed it is only 168 KB (172,521 bytes) so a considerable saving but nowhere near the 2 KB level as it needs fonts to display the text and describe the bloated structure for readability.
Can we compress the file further (lossless)? To not affect those contents and the answer is yes. We can use a PDF Size Optimiser and reduce the support fonts etc. down to a total with text of 113 KB (116,245 bytes).
NOTE there is no improvement in compression possible in an already compressed PDF all we are doing is improving some refactoring of already compressed objects. So the source compressed file is composed of /Size 336 objects and the now smaller file is more concentrated as /Size 335 objects. Thus better compressed overall by resequencing into one less object.
For methodology see https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt

